# React native client can connect to Node.js Back-end with axios

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, expo

I try to input an email with axios.post and to send this to the back-end. It fails with:

```
Request failed with status code 500 node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError
```

my code:

```
_onPressButton61 = async () => {
    if (this.validate(this.state.userData.email)) {
        try {
            let result = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.4:3000/users', this.state.userData);

            this.props.navigation.navigate('Splash');
            console.log(result);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            Alert.alert('This email was used');
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("NU POTI TRECE");
        Alert.alert('This email is invalid');
    }

}
```

Comment: The error 500 is usually coming from your server and not from the app.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the server code for the `users` api in your backend so we can have a look. Also, please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)